# Automatically Add Date/Time and Build Number to Info.plist Xcode

Tags: xcode, bash

I am looking to automatically add the build date and build number to my Info.plist file for only the builds where I archive the application for iOS.

### My script is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
# This was taken from variations from:
# http://davedelong.com/blog/2009/04/15/incrementing-build-numbers-xcode

if [ "$CONFIGURATION" != "Release" ]
then
exit
fi


buildPlist="$SRCROOT/$PROJECT_NAME/$PROJECT_NAME-Info.plist"


# Get the existing buildVersion and buildNumber values from the buildPlist
buildVersion=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBuildVersion" "$buildPlist")

buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBuildNumber" "$buildPlist")

buildDate=$(date "+%s")


# Increment the buildNumber
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))

# Set the version numbers in the buildPlist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBuildNumber $buildNumber" "$buildPlist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c  "Set :CFBuildDate $buildDate" "$buildPlist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildVersion.$buildNumber" "$buildPlist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $buildVersion.$buildNumber" "$buildPlist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleLongVersionString $buildVersion.$buildNumber.$buildDate" "$buildPlist"
```

Everything here is working great, and I have this script running as a build phase right after target dependencies in the build phase tab.

The only issue I am having is that the project seems to be built using the old values for Info.plist, not the new ones.

In other words, if I archive the application and examine the Info.plist file in the resulting ipa, they reflect the old values. Looking at the Info.plist in the project, however, shows that the script did indeed execute correctly, but not in time for the project to be build using the old Info.plist.

Is there any solution to this?

This seems like something that could be fixed relatively easily but I'm surprised not as many people have been asking about this issue in the articles posted on this topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out the answer was incredibly straightforward. All that was necessary was to turn on Info.plist preprocessing and then use the `__TIMESTAMP__` preprocessor directive.

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you did this? Couldn't find any solid docs on the matter.

Comment: In build settings, make sure that "All" (not basic) is selected, then search for "preprocess info.plist file". By default it's set to "no". Change to "yes". As user ecbtin suggests, if you use the directive "__TIMESTAMP__" in a string field in the plist, it will map to the current time. You can get cutesy by providing a header file containing preprocessor constants - set that file by searching for "Info.plist Preprocessor Prefix File"

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the `Info.plist` file is processed before anything else run. From examining the build log this involves converting it to binary and placing it inside the build directory.

To fix this, the versioning script must modify the file in the build directory, and *not* the file in the project directory. The path to the `Info.plist` in the build directory can be obtained by combining the following environmental variables which are set during the build process:

```
plistpath=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}
```

If you now modify the file at `$plistpath` you will be modifying the plist that will end up being packaged into the final application.

I use this technique to get build information into releases, with the versioning script running as the first build phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Archiving the application builds the app, which increments the build count. You could try to execute that script before it compiles binaries (just drag the Run Script all the way up in Build Phases). If that doesn't work, I'm sure it's possible to do a conditional increment by 2 if you're building to archive.

Comment: Dragging all the way up doesn't work. I'm not as worried as the build number, as I am about the build timestamp. I use this number within the app to check for updates online. So imagine I haven't updated the app for a while and I make a lot of changes and then archive it and get ready to submit the update. The timestamp that gets bundled with Info.plist is from the last time the app was built, potentially months and months ago. Then when checking for updates, the app will think it's a lot older than it actually is. I need a solution to this without having to manually set the date every build.

Comment: The only other option I can think of is building one more time right before archiving. Since you check for the Release configuration, you could create a Pre-release configuration that you add to that if statement. Duplicate the Debug configuration and call it Pre-release maybe?

Comment: Yup that'll do it. I was just hoping there was an easier solution that wasn't as temperamental. Seems like a pretty common need but I'll fall back to that if it's my only choice.

Comment: I'm sure there is. However, I've spent many hours online trying to figure out similar stuff, but there's not much documentation on these things, so as long as these things are somewhat automated, I'm happy.

Comment: The "somewhat" is what's really bothering me here. Remembering to build twice sounds easy but it's just another thing that isn't automated. The next step in my workflow is to upload the IPA to the server, where it scrapes the datetime that was just written. In the app that people are running, it does a web request and compares the datetime stored on the server with the datetime in the app's Info.plist. If I remember to build twice the first time, but then forget another time, the entire workflow gets abrupted. I'd love for there to be an easy fix to this.

Comment: It appear that dragging all the way to the top works in XCode 9.2.